# Clear finish for wet erase board on wood

Tags: finishing, water-protection

I am fairly new to the woodworking scene, and am looking for how to turn a piece of wood into a usable wet erase board, with a clear finish.  Doing some digging, I've found a couple of possible solutions for dry erase, but can't seem to find anything for wet erase markers.

One thought I had was to use something like polyurethane, which seems to work at least for short term markings.  I would like the board to be resistant to long term markings though also, so I'm not sure if this approach is viable.

An alternative thought it to use a thin material over the wood, but since I would like the entire piece to be markable, I am hoping to find a solution in a finishing product.

Not sure it affects the end goal, but I would also like to be able to have a design or pattern on the wood before the finish is applied.

To summarize: My end goal hope is to have a board with a design on it, that can be marked over with wet-erase markers and erased, even with long term markings.

Greatly appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I think a number of harder film finishes *might* work here (certainly yes in the short term) but the long-term requirement could be a problem. If ever the surface gets even slightly marred (microscopic scratches from abrasion, which I think are inevitable given enough time) that sort of defect can hold on to stuff that stains far more than the 'closed' surface of the same material when pristine. And related to this, I think this will need a full film of a high-gloss finish (since matt finishes are innately micro-textured), how does that sit with you aesthetically?

Comment: Any idea what the solvents used in the wet-erase markers are? If the compatibility is right (e.g. not an alcohol-based solvent) shellac might be a good surface finish. It would eliminate having to sand the surface smooth to periodically rejuvenate it.

Comment: @gnicko, I'd have expected this anyway but a more thorough search suggest that the formula, make to make, varies more than some sites imply or claim; this is made worse by so many sites using scraped content now. My prior experience with wet-erase markers, which I thought was very out of date but apparently not, was that is could be far more difficult to erase than the on-pack directions led one to believe.

Comment: @Graphus - True. My experience with wet-erase (and dry-erase) is that after so many days/weeks/months the stuff doesn't want to erase hardly at all. I think the intention is that the markings will be erased within minutes--during the course of a lecture/meting, etc. or shortly after conclusion.

Comment: @gnicko I know from experience that dry erase markers become semi-permanent if not erased within 24 hours. The fix is to "wet erase" - write over anything that's stuck on with a fresh dry erase marker and erase immediately. _Usually_ that will work but it's not guaranteed 100%.

Comment: @Graphus That is what I am thinking too.  More than anything now, I think I am looking for what the best solution would be for something like that.  I am actually looking for whatever the least reflective would be, since I would like the markings to be visible.  Appreciate your reply, sorry if I was delayed in responding!

Comment: @gnicko Though I'm not certain of it, I think the main reason to use wet erase is for longer term markings, and for markings that wouldn't smear/smug with hands or anything rubbing across the board.    The markers I am looking to use are the [Expo Vis-a-Vis Wet Erase (nontoxic)](https://www.amazon.com/Wet-Erase-Marker-Point-4-Color-SAN16074/dp/B00A40DBSE/ref=sr_1_4?crid=6ZWEPXHZLRK4&keywords=expo%2Bvisa-a-vis%2Bwet%2Berase%2Bmarkers%2Bfine%2Bpoint&qid=1675215899&sprefix=expo%2Bvisa%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-4&th=1).  Also thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of without doing a search to see if any new products are out there, is to put a good coat of epoxy to cover the whole surface.  it can take a bit of abuse and should work. And after a lot of time if it starts getting beat up, you should be able to take some very fine sand paper and clean it up again.

Comment: Epoxy is the only material I could think of that there's a good chance of working in the long term — both for marks that are left on for a long time, and also to remain protective over a long service life. But I think once it starts to get marked (even the finest scratches from cleaning might be enough) the surface would need to be fully repolished to return to its original ability.

Comment: @Graphus, right, that is kind of what I was thinking too.

Comment: I completely overlooked epoxy, though I haven't used it, or am unsure how this would be as a finish.  Definitely looking for the least glossy finish possible, but I think this may be the way to go.  Thanks for the replies here.

Comment: @Attict, *"Definitely looking for the least glossy finish possible"* This is I suspect a quest for unobtainium. You can certainly try a test with something lower in sheen, but I think even IF you're happy with the performance initially that a longer-term test will prove disappointing as many of the Comments have suggested. And it would be an expensive thing to test out since smaller packs of epoxy are notoriously expensive per unit volume (even more so than the innate high price of epoxy to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

I know you are looking for a wood finish that is dry erase marker safe. My suggestion is to finish the wood including the design with regular finish products and mount glass on the surface.

Even a whiteboard will stain over time. The best dry erase surface - one that will last - is glass

You would get glass cut to fit and use mirror mounts or a frame to hold the glass to your surface.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Displays2go web site](https://www.displays2go.com/Guide/Dry-Erase-Vs-Wet-Erase-Markers-Understanding-Differences-10), wet erase markers use a paste-like material as the medium. The linked article suggests water as the cleaning substance, in a damp cloth:

> Wet Erase Markers
>
> Wet erase markers, also commonly referred to as wet-wipe markers, can
> be used on any non-porous surface, which makes them great for a
> variety of materials. But wet-erase ink has a few major differences
> from typical dry erase markers. First, wet erase pens use a paste
> instead of an alcohol-based ink which makes the markings
> semi-permanent. This means that a normal whiteboard eraser will not
> remove the markings, but a simple damp cloth will remove it quite
> easily. Another advantage is that wet-erase markings will not fade or
> bubble under intense heat, so they can be used with marker boards that
> feature illumination, as well as projector lamps. A little known
> benefit of wet-erase ink is that it is much less likely to cause an
> allergic reaction than dry-erase formulas.

This would indicate that almost any surface sealer unaffected by water will perform as needed. Unless subject to abrasion or impact, a polyurethane or epoxy coating should meet your requirements, as will a clear coat application.

Comment: What's a "clear coat of paint"? FWIW the long-term requirement that the OP has may make this a lot less clearcut than it first appears.

Comment: Spray can marked Clear?

Comment: But that's not *paint*. Paint has pigment in it, clear finishes are clear finishes. The two things shouldn't be conflated. Edit: and FYI some clear coats are lacquers, many of which have poor stain resistance.